# javascript code is working fine in Internet Explorer but not working in Firefox and Google chrome

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

**The below javascript code is working fine in Internet Explorer but not working in Firefox and Google chrome**

```
var prand=11211411110311410111511510511111068508491;
//This is the value of variable prand that i get after calculation 
prand =   parseInt(prand.substring(0, 10)) + parseInt(prand.substring(10, prand.length))).toString(); 
//After this calculation I'm getting the expected  result in IE,but the value is coming different in Firefox and Chrome
```

I have sorted out some more information ...

On alerting `parseInt(prand.substring(10, prand.length))` , it's showing
**`232332021465786650000` on IE** and **`3.114101115115105e+29` on Chrome**

Comment: http://floating-point-gui.de/. Your number is too big.

Comment: Try actually running your code before posting. There too many things wrong with it.

Comment: I have already run the code. Without that I cant tel the  values coming on IE and Chrome Mr sabof

Answer (score 3):

if you wish to use substring, make sure your original variable *is* a string. Chrome finds that your prand variable has no quotes, so it tries to convert it into the largest number. IE on the other hand gives up and uses it as a string instead. Try declaring your variable as a string:

```
var prand = "11211411110311410111511510511111068508491";
```

Even then, the value of 311410111511510511111068508491 is too big to fit into a single integer. You might want to rethink your logic.

Comment: actually i'm getting the value 11211411110311410111511510511111068508491 to variable prand  after a set of calculations.So its not possible to convert it to string

Comment: It's still a number in IE8. Which IE did you test it with?